# Use PHP GD in Laravel get garbled

Tags: php, laravel, php-gd

I dispatch php gd in my controller, here's the code

```
class getSmallImageController extends Controller
{
    public function getImg(request $request)
    {
        // Get the image from local file. The image must be 300*200 size.
        //change $img to your own path
        $img_path = '/home/jonnyy/PhpstormProjects/zcapt/app/repository/Image/1.jpg';

        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($img_path);
        $img_size = getimagesize($img_path);
        if ($img_size[0] != 300 || $img_size[1] != 200)
            die("image size must be 300*200");

        //get value of authID from init.php
        $response = app('App\Http\Controllers\initController')->index($request);
        $authID = $response->getOriginalContent()['authID'];

        // Calculate the diagonal coordinate for that square
        $position_x_1 = DB::table('inits')
            ->select('x')
            ->where('authID', '=', $authID)
            ->inRandomOrder()
            ->first();

        $position_y_1 = DB::table('inits')
            ->select('y')
            ->where('authID', '=', $authID)
            ->inRandomOrder()
            ->first();


// Create a small image with height 50 and width 50

        $img_small = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 50);
// Copy one part of the large image (the image with size 300*200) to small part of image

        imagecopy($img_small, $img, 0, 0, current($position_x_1), current($position_y_1), 50, 50);
// Change brightness of the picture
       imagefilter($img_small, IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS, 50);
        $position_1 = 0;
        $position_2 = 50;
// Adding some blur in to small picture
        for ($i = 50; $i < 120; $i = $i + 6) {
            imagerectangle($img_small, $position_1, $position_1, $position_2, $position_2, imagecolorallocatealpha($img_small, 255, 255, 255, $i));
            $position_1 = $position_1 + 1;
            $position_2 = $position_2 - 1;
        }

// Set header in type jpg

        ;
// Generate image

        header("Content-type: image/jpg");
// Generate image
        imagejpeg($img_small);
// Release memory
        imagedestroy($img_small);
        ;
        imagedestroy($img);
    }
}
```

Got this garbled
[image]

But When I dd() the last line of my code,

```
dd(imagedestroy($img))
```

return the picture I want.
[image]

By the way, the GD library works in another controller which I dispatched for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't the way the Laravel with MVC should work. As a dirty solution I believe that put `exit;` after `imagedestroy()` could work. Another option would be to save the image to disk and display to the user.

The following option is to save in memory and then send to the user. If your page/application isn't accessed too frequently, it can work well for you.

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($img_small);
imagedestroy($img_small);
$image_data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$response = \Response::make($image_data, 200);
$response->header("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
return $response;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it works for me, anyway I'll rebuild my code in the future because I'm just new working with laravel lol.